# Could two condition_variable.wait_for used with a single lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

If codes like

```
std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable cond;
bool is_ok = false;

void func() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    if (!cond.wait_for(lck,
                        std::chrono::seconds(3),
                        [&] { return is_ok; })) {
        std::cout << "wait 1" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "ok 1" << std::endl;
    if (!cond.wait_for(lck,
                        std::chrono::seconds(8),
                        [&] { return is_ok; })) {
        std::cout << "wait 2" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "ok 2" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::thread t(func);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mut);
        is_ok = true;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    if (t.joinable()){
        t.join();
    }    
}
```

As show https://godbolt.org/

Then what is the running sequence between `thread t` and `main thread`?
Are both `cond.wait_for` valid?

In addition, the program ends with some error

```
Killed - processing time exceeded
Program terminated with signal: SIGKILL
```

Where does it come?

Comment: `Killed - processing time exceeded` is not from c++ or from your code, its the platform you are using considering the time you are occupying it as too long.

Comment: I mean surely it hints at an issue in your code, but in princple "processing time exceeded" mean just that you exceeded the available time, not more. YOu can write code that is totally fine, and sleeps for an hour before it exits, it will run fine anywhere but not on godbolt and other platforms that are picky about how long someone uses their cpus

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can of course `wait_for` a condition variable multiple times in its lifetime, and you can reuse the same lock object.

But you seem to misunderstand how condition variables work, because you never signal the one you have (by calling `notify_one` or `notify_all` from the main thread). So your wait attempts just time out.

And since godbolt limits your program's execution wall time to far less than the 11 seconds you sleep for in total, your job just gets killed. You should do tests like this on your local computer.

Comment: Please add the missing `notify_one`/`notify_all` part two your answer. Otherwise your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @MikevanDyke like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, how else would you wait for a change in condition in a loop?

To correct the code, reset the `is_ok` when the first wait in `func()` is done and set `is_ok` and notify twice (in a loop) in `main()` since you wait twice.